# Jinja2 cannot read a template file with a particular full path

Tags: flask, jinja2, template-engine

Normally, jinja2 render_template method asks a string of a full path of html.
I do as the format below but it still raise the error.

```
render_template('/var/www/xyz/template/_base_front.html', {"data":"pc"})
```

I try opening the path by using nano editor, it works fine.
A particular file is full permission of read, write, and execute.
[image: A screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to place the file in the `templates` folder (default folder if you didn't define your own `template_folder`) and provide a relative path to it (probably `_base_front.html` in your case).

from [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates):

> To render a template you can use the render_template() method. All you have to do is provide the name of the template and the variables you want to pass to the template engine as keyword arguments. Here’s a simple example of how to render a template:

> Flask will look for templates in the templates folder. So if your application is a module, this folder is next to that module, if it’s a package it’s actually inside your package: